# IE10 always goes to error section of $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to read a JSON file using jQuery AJAX. IE10 always goes to the `error` section. FF and Chrome are working fine. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://aaa.bbb.com/select?&json.wrf=callback",
    // data: "{}",
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (msg) {
        // do something
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("error");
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: What is the error printed (with alert) ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  - error is that it alerts the error section alerts. alerts "error" and [object Object]

Comment: Use `console.log(msg)` instead to see the full detail.

Comment: console.log(msg) outputs [object Object]